# How can i do a mouse click on Kendoui Grid and popup a window using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, telerik, kendo-grid

I am doing a double click on kendoui grid with the following code

```
     dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = this;
            grid.tbody.find("tr").dblclick(function (e)
            {
                var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
                alert(dataItem.Name); 

            });
        }
```

I get the row data correctly, but how can i do this using right mouseclick which gives a drop down option selection , cant find any demos by Telerik ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`javaScript`** `oncontextmenu`:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    var grid = this;

    grid.tbody.find("tr").dblclick(function (e) {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        alert(dataItem.Name);
    });

    grid.tbody.find("tr").on('contextmenu', function (a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        alert(dataItem.name)
    });
}
```

This will disable the right-click context menu and add your functionality when you right-click the grids `tr` element.

Example: [Right click event (oncontextmenu)](https://dojo.telerik.com/aSaMiTEr)